# 2012 Jeep Grand Cherokee security code

Tags: electrical, starting, security

[image]

My jeep grand cherokee 3.6 2012 radio wants secury code and I don't have a use manual. The car cannot start.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a well known issue with the Jeep anti-theft system starting in 2012. The dealer can get the code for you. You will need to provide the VIN of the vehicle the radio came out of and the radio's serial number.

If this is a recurring issue, the recommended solution is a firmware update. Which is also done by the dealer or any reputable auto shop.

You can also take it to a car audio shop. They can also retrieve the code.

However, there may be something else wrong. Usually this issue does not come with a no start. I would check for other Diagnostic Trouble Codes and troubleshoot them first.

I would also remove the radio fuse and see if it starts.

Comment: Is it possible to get the code digitaly?

Comment: @RebonengMakoa Like on the internet? No, not that I am aware of. There used to be a guy that provided an online tool to retrieve the code. But I don't think he's in business anymore. His website looks like a blog now. You need to reach out to Jeep's Corporate office or the dealer. They shouldn't charge you anything.